# SQL Server custom growing sequence generation

Tags: sql, sql-server, concurrency, triggers

Suppose I have a table like this.

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
  id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  condition int NOT NULL, 
  result int NULL
)
```

Based on `condition` value I generate `result` in after insert trigger. I take max `result` for the current condition and increment it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [t_Trigger]
ON t
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  IF (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT condition) FROM INSERTED) > 1
    BEGIN
      RAISERROR('Cannot insert records with more than one condition simultaneously', 16, 2)
      ROLLBACK TRAN
      RETURN
    END

  DECLARE @cond int;
  DECLARE @maxResult int;
  SET @cond = (SELECT TOP(1) condition FROM INSERTED);
  SET @maxResult = (SELECT MAX(result) FROM t WHERE condition = @cond);

  UPDATE t
  SET @maxResult = t.result = ISNULL(@maxResult, 0) + 1
  FROM t as t
  JOIN INSERTED i
    ON t.id = i.id;    
END
```

The task is to have a growing sequence in `result` for each `condition` value after each insert.

My question is about thread safety. If two or more sessions insert several records into `t`, can duplicate `result` values appear for the same `condition`? How to avoid that?

For now I have a variant to create a record in my config table to store xml record with current `max(result)` for each condition. Something like this:

```
<MaxResults>
  <Condition value="1">5</Condition>
  <Condition value="2">7</Condition>
  ...
</MaxResults>
```

So in `t_Trigger` I grab maxResult for current condition, update `t` and update config record. But the same question appears concerning thread safe xml access etc.

Comment: Why doesn't the `identity` column suffice?

Comment: Column `result` itself won't be identity cause it can contain duplicate values but for different `condition` values. It's like having unique index on both `condition` and `result`. Besides I'd like to have no gaps in each `condition`'s sequence.

Comment: Your trigger has some issues. First of all you have a select top 1 but there is no order by. That means you don't actually know which row from inserted you are going to get. Your trigger as coded is unable to handle multiple row actions correctly. If what you want is a seamless incrementing value this won't work anyway unless you do some more stuff in a delete trigger. I would recommend you use ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Condition order by Result) when you want to select your data. This ensures you always have a number with no gaps.

Comment: Sean, please notice in trigger I first check if all inserted rows have the same `condition`. That's why top 1 will return the single value anyway. Tested it on multiple rows inserted - everything ok.

Comment: Why not do the calculation when you retrieve data rather than when you store it?

Comment: Gordon, generated `result` value depends on the data already stored in DB (previous `result`s for the current `condition`), so why should I move this logic from DB level?